# How to make a request by using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, multipartform-data

[This is actual image of POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afHzE.png)[Upload Images using Android Retrofit, how to make Multipart request using retrofit][2]

I am sending multiple image files using Retrofit along with string data but on server side string data is missing

My Save register API
`/*Save register*/
    @Multipart
    @POST("Events/SaveRegistration")
    Call<ModelRegisterMember> saveRegister(
            @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files, @Query("data") String memberData
    );
// body of request`
 private void uploadMemberInfo(List parts, ModelMakeMemberRegister allMembers) {

```
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();


    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<ModelRegisterMember> call = apiInterface.saveRegister(parts, new Gson().toJson(allMembers));


    Log.e("Req", call.request().toString());
    Log.e("Body", call.request().body().toString());
    Log.e("Body", call.request().headers().toString());
    Log.e("json", new Gson().toJson(allMembers));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelRegisterMember>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ModelRegisterMember> call, Response<ModelRegisterMember> response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            MyUtils.showToast(mContext, response.body().getMessage());
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ModelRegisterMember> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("err", t.toString());
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


}`
```

What wrong happen with request I don't know please help

Answer (score 3):

```
fun uploadFile(@Url url:String, @Part("AppGuid") guid:RequestBody,
              @Part("UserGuid") uuid:RequestBody? = null,
              @Part("DeviceToken") token:RequestBody,
              @Part("UserAppGuid") uAppGuid:RequestBody,
              @Part("FileName") fileName:RequestBody,
              @Part("FileType") fileType:RequestBody, @Part file: MultipartBody.Part): Call<JsonElement>
```